# Python-TypeError: unbound method configure() must be called with Label instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run the code, TK form should pop up But i am getting this error:

```
File "PycharmProjects/untitled/tkhello4.py", line 11, in resize
    Label.config(font='Helvetica -%d bold' % scale.get())
TypeError: unbound method configure() must be called with Label instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

What could be wrong? Thank you overmuch.

Below is my code.

```
from Tkinter import *


def resize(ev=None):
    Label.config(font='Helvetica -%d bold' % scale.get())

top = Tk()
top.geometry('250x150')

Lable = Label(top, text='Hello World!',
              font='Helvetica -12 bold')
Lable.pack(fill=Y, expand=1)

scale= Scale(top, from_=10, to=40,
             orient=HORIZONTAL, command=resize)
scale.set(12)
scale.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

quit = Button(top, text='QUIT', command=top.quit, activeforeground='white', activebackground='red')
quit.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: You probably meant to use `Lable` rather than `Label` there. You should give your instance a more useful and easily-distinguished name, and follow the PEP8 style of instances having lower case names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . it has work...I am a new coder , there are a lot of things to learn, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a class `Label` and a variable `Lable` which seems a **recipe for confusion** ... which is exactly what has happened.

```
# here you refer to the class Label
Label.config(font='Helvetica -%d bold' % scale.get())
```

Should be

```
# but you should be using the instance Lable
Lable.config(font='Helvetica -%d bold' % scale.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your label to something that is not part of a built in function.

Keep this in mind when naming any variable. If you confuse the name space things can get messy. Always write variable names in a way that will avoid messing with the built in functions or any imported functions.

just rename your Label like the following. It is always best to follow [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide to prevent this kind of problem.

```
def resize(ev=None):
    my_lable.config(font='Helvetica -%d bold' % scale.get())


my_lable = Label(top, text='Hello World!', font='Helvetica -12 bold')
my_lable.pack(fill=Y, expand=1)
```